# Add custom button into the Price Book Entry Search Layouts

Tags: custom, button, search, pricebook, page-layout

I would like to add custom button into the "Price Book Entry Search Layouts".

In the [documentation](http:///ui/setup/layout/ListLayouts?type=PricebookEntry&setupid=PricebookEntrySearchLayouts), it says : 
[image]
it speaks about custom button. :/

I speak about this page : /p/opp/SelectSearch?addTo={opportunity.Id}

I would like something like that :
[image]

Do you know if it is possible to do that in Salesforce please ?

Aurélien

Comment: Pretty sure you can't - you would need to write your own VF page to override the Add Product/Edit All buttons to replace it, and include the custom button on the VF page.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

I thinked that too.

So, I have to override the search layout with a Visualforce Page. :)

Comment: Can you open this page as lightning ?